# MySQL (PHP) does not order Array according to SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem when I'm retrieving conversations from my MySQL database. When I run the query on
phpMyAdmin, it gives me the order;

1. 41 (2021-07-24)
2. 371 (2021-07-20)
3. 361 (2021-07-19)
4. 351 (2021-07-17)
5. 21 (2021-07-11)

But when I run my code in PHP, I get this order;

1. 371 (2021-07-20)
2. 361 (2021-07-19)
3. 351 (2021-07-17)
4. 41 (2021-07-24)
5. 21 (2021-07-11)

Heres the code in PHP:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    
    $requestId = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['requestid']);
    $requestIdPost = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['requestid']);

    if($requestId == 1){ //Find all unique chat_id's
        $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['userid']);
        $chatid = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['chatid']);
        $sender = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['sender']);
        
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT chat_id FROM chatdb WHERE (account_id='$id' OR counterpart='$id') 
        AND active=1 ORDER BY chat_time DESC";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){
            for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
                $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $chatid = $rs['chat_id'];
                $chatid = utf8_encode($chatid);
                $points[$i][0]=($chatid);
            }
            echo (json_encode($points));
        }
        else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $chatid = $rs['chat_id'];
            $chatid = utf8_encode($chatid);
            echo json_encode($chatid);
        }
        else{
            echo (0);
        }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know why the array created by my For-loop messes up the order of the chat-ids?
Keep in mind that the array (if #rows > 1) is echoed back to an ajax request in javascript:

```
function populateChatList(){
    var loginId = getCookie("a_user");
    var newArrayLoginId = loginId.split(',');
    var accountid = newArrayLoginId[0];
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: './PHP/inbox.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                requestid: 1,
                userid: accountid,
            },
            success: function(response){
                var response = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response)
                if(Array.isArray(response) == false){ //single chatbox
                    sessionStorage.setItem('c_id', `${response}`);
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: './PHP/inbox.php',
                            dataType: 'text',
                            method: 'GET',
                            data: {
                                requestid: 2,
                                chatid: sessionStorage.getItem('c_id'),
                            },
                            success: function(response){
                                var query = JSON.parse(response);
                                if(query !== 0){
                                    conversationPopulate(query);
                                }
                                else{ //no messages, display no-message-svg
                                    document.getElementById('no-message-svg-wrapper').style.display = "flex";
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    );
                }
                else if(response.length > 1){ //multiple chatbox
                    response.forEach(element => {
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: './PHP/inbox.php',
                                dataType: 'text',
                                method: 'GET',
                                data: {
                                    requestid: 2,
                                    chatid: element[0],
                                },
                                success: function(response){
                                    var query = JSON.parse(response);
                                    conversationPopulate(query, element);
                                },
                            }
                        );
                    });
                }
                else if(response == 0){
                    document.getElementById('noconversations').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('noconversations').innerText = "Inga Konversationer"
                }
            },
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: If you just run `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` and `print_r(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));` is order incorrect? The `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){ for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){ $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result);` seems like it could be simplified with a `while` loop. The `utf8_encode` I also don't think is needed.

Comment: It did not retrieve the query in the correct order...
I'll look into the option of adopting a while loop instead of a for loop, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a column in `ORDER BY` that is not specified inside `SELECT DISTINCT` clause. MySQL should not allow this unless you're using obsolete, discouraged behavior. Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` so that you can use aggregate functions in `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT chat_id
FROM chatdb
WHERE ...
GROUP BY chat_id
ORDER BY MAX(chat_time) DESC -- find max time for each chat_id group and
                             -- order the overall results by that aggregate
```

Comment: This was actually great, and works perfectly! Thank you very much for the help!